# Rails 5.2 + ReactJS: simple rendering issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I am using Fernando Villalobos' [Rails + ReactJS tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers) and have run into a (hopefully) simple rendering issue.

I'm using Rails 5.2.1 and the react-rails gem v2.4.7.

Here is the controller logic:

```
def index
  @records = Record.all
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<%= react_component "Records", { data: @records } %>
```

Here is the CoffeeScript:

```
  @Records = React.createClass
    render: ->
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'records'
        React.DOM.h2
          className: 'title'
          'Records'
```

At this point in the tutorial, the user should see the div, the H2 tag and "Records".

Google Developer's Console confirms React has inserted a `<div data-react-class="Records" data-react-props="..."></div>` into the HTML - but I don't see any sign of the `<h2>Records</h2>`. There are no reported errors or warnings. I've tried using equivalent JSX syntax with no change in results. The javascripts/application.js file looks correct too:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That tutorial was written 3 years ago using `react-rails` v1 current version is 2.4.7 maybe try to find a newer tutorial?

Comment: Here are a few https://medium.com/quick-code/simple-rails-crud-app-with-react-frontend-using-react-rails-gem-b708b89a9419 , https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/building-a-crud-interface-with-react-and-ruby-on-rails or [Free Complete Course](https://learnetto.com/users/hrishio/courses/the-complete-react-on-rails-5-course)

Comment: Thanks. I started a 2nd lesson from Learnetto (late 2017) and ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have `<div data-react-class="Records" data-react-props="..."></div>` rendered but not processed you properly miss either the `webpacker` setup (in case you don't go with `sprockets`) or just the 'JavaScript pack tag'.

Have you followed the instructions from the 'Get started' section of the `react-rails` gem? See [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#get-started-with-webpacker)

Instructions in short:

#### Add Gems

Add `webpacker` and `react-rails` to your gemfile

#### Run installers

```
$ bundle install
$ rails webpacker:install
$ rails webpacker:install:react
$ rails generate react:install
```

#### Link the JavaScript pack

add `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` to your view

#### Generate component

this step may be optional (since you have already written your component)

```
rails g react:component my_subdirectory/HelloWorld greeting:string
```

#### Render it

```
<%= react_component("HelloWorld", { greeting: "Hello" }) %>
```

or in your case, as you did `<%= react_component "Records", { data: @records } %>`

#### In case it's not working

Try Server side rendering, `<%= react_component("Records", { data: @records }, {prerender: true}) %>`

Start `webpack-dev-server` to see what it has to complain about: `bin/webpack-dev-server`